# How to read multiple text file at once and find particular text between two text?

Tags: python, string, list, find

This code works fine if I operate with one text file at a time. But if I uncomment last three lines and comment print statement to operate this code with multiple files at once then this code is not working. It does not gives any error but also does not give any output!

```
import pathlib

def extract_text(filename):
    start = "#patient_name').val('"
    end = "');$('#father_name"
    with open(filename, 'rt') as myfile:
        text = myfile.read()
        return text[text.find(start)+len(start):text.rfind(end)]


print(extract_text('new.txt'))
    #patients = []
    #for filename in pathlib.Path('.').glob('*.txt'):
     #patients.append(extract_text(filename))
```

This are my temporary text files with the values I want in it:

[image]

This is the output if I use the code for one file at a time

[image: Embedded image]

And this is the output when I use this code for multiple files:

[image: Embedded output image]

**Note: This code are not completely written by me. Someone helped me on my last question on Stack Overflow**.

I have also another code which I got from [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-read-multiple-text-files-from-folder-in-python/) but it is also not working.

Comment: You tried to change the indentations to be correct?

Comment: everything looks fine to me but don't know why its not working! No indentation error or syntax error!!

Comment: Why theses lines are indented they should be at the start of the line.                                             ```patients = []
    for filename in pathlib.Path('.').glob('*.txt'):
     patients.append(extract_text(filename))```

Comment: Ok bro this worked @Bashi Thanks a lot.. Sometimes this small things get you in trouble lol again thanks buddy!!

Answer (score 1):

Use Glob instead of Pathlib.

```
import glob

def extract_text(filename):
    start = "#patient_name').val('"
    end = "');$('#father_name"
    with open(filename, 'rt') as myfile:
        text = myfile.read()
    myfile.close()
    return text[text.find(start)+len(start):text.rfind(end)]

#using glob for getting all text files instead of Path module
patients = []
for filename in glob.glob('./*.txt'):
    print(extract_text(filename))
```

It'll work.

Comment: Tried... Not working brother! I tried printing patients, myfile, text, filename but nothing works!!

Comment: I updated can you try this.

Comment: Yes your code is working but result output is in List format i.e [name1, name2, name3, name4]. But if we print(extract_text(filename)) then it prints all names in raw format and also one name in one line. by the way Thanks a lot for helping bro!

Comment: Yeah cool, I've edited it and added comments in case of future references.

Comment: If it's correct, can you choose the right answer, for future use. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

As @Bashi said in comment It was indentation error and the final working code here

```
import pathlib

def extract_text(filename):
    start = "#patient_name').val('"
    end = "');$('#father_name"
    with open(filename, 'rt') as myfile:
        text = myfile.read()
        return text[text.find(start)+len(start):text.rfind(end)]

patients = []
for filename in pathlib.Path('.').glob('*.txt'):
    print(extract_text(filename))
```